# Parse Wavefront OBJ using ReadP

Tags: parsing, haskell

I've been reading Haskell tutorials and books for a while, but I never actually did serious stuff with it. This is my first attempt.

It parses an OBJ-file in text format. Later on I will add some mesh-representation and more geometry stuff.

Could you please review my code and check for "haskeliness" (like, best practices and maybe if something can be done in a simpler way)?
Also I have the feeling, that the `ObjFileLine` type is redundant. But I can't think of a way to avoid it.

An OBJ-file looks basically like this (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#File_format):

```
# List of geometric vertices, with (x, y, z [,w]) coordinates, w is optional and defaults to 1.0.
v 0.123 0.234 0.345 1.0
v ...
# List of texture coordinates, in (u, [,v ,w]) coordinates, these will vary between 0 and 1. v, w are optional and default to 0.
vt 0.500 1 [0]
vt ...
# List of vertex normals in (x,y,z) form; normals might not be unit vectors.
vn 0.707 0.000 0.707
vn ...
# Parameter space vertices in ( u [,v] [,w] ) form; free form geometry statement ( see below )
vp 0.310000 3.210000 2.100000
vp ...
# Polygonal face element (see below)
f 1 2 3
f 3/1 4/2 5/3
f 6/4/1 3/5/3 7/6/5
f 7//1 8//2 9//3
f ...
# Line element (see below)
l 5 8 1 2 4 9
```

I have one file `Obj/Obj.hs` for the data types, which looks like this:

```
module Obj.Obj where

import Data.List

-- mesh vertices
data ObjVertex =
    Vertex Double Double Double
    | Vertex4 Double Double Double Double
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjVertex where
    show (Vertex a b c) = "v " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " " ++ show c
    show (Vertex4 a b c d) = show (Vertex a b c) ++ " " ++ show d

-- uv coordinates for textures
data ObjTexture =
    Texture1 Double
    | Texture2 Double Double
    | Texture3 Double Double Double
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjTexture where
    show (Texture1 a) = "vt " ++ show a
    show (Texture2 a b) = show (Texture1 a) ++ " " ++ show b
    show (Texture3 a b c) = show (Texture2 a b) ++ " " ++ show c

-- face normals
data ObjNormal = 
    Normal Double Double Double
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjNormal where
    show (Normal a b c) = "vn " ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ " " ++ show c

-- parameter space
data ObjParameter = 
    Parameter1 Double
    | Parameter2 Double Double
    | Parameter3 Double Double Double
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjParameter where
    show (Parameter1 a) = "vp " ++ show a
    show (Parameter2 a b) = show (Parameter1 a) ++ " " ++ show b
    show (Parameter3 a b c) = show (Parameter2 a b) ++ " " ++ show c

-- face connectivites
data ObjVertexIndex = 
    VertexIndex Int
    | VertexTexture Int Int
    | VertexNormal Int Int
    | VertexTextureNormal Int Int Int
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjVertexIndex where
    show (VertexIndex a) = show a
    show (VertexTexture a b) = show a ++ "/" ++ show b
    show (VertexNormal a b) = show a ++ "//" ++ show b
    show (VertexTextureNormal a b c) = show a ++ "/" ++ show b ++ "/" ++ show c

-- faces
data ObjFace = Face [ObjVertexIndex]
deriving Eq

instance Show ObjFace where
    show (Face vertices) = "f " ++ (intercalate " " $ map show vertices)

-- polylines
data ObjPolyLine = Line [Int]
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjPolyLine where
    show (Line vertices) = "l " ++ (intercalate " " $ map show vertices)

data ObjFile = File
    { vertices   :: [ObjVertex]
    , textures   :: [ObjTexture]
    , normals    :: [ObjNormal]
    , parameters :: [ObjParameter]
    , faces      :: [ObjFace]
    , polylines  :: [ObjPolyLine]
    }

instance Show ObjFile where
    show file = unlines $ concat [
        fmap show (vertices file),
        fmap show (textures file),
        fmap show (normals file),
        fmap show (parameters file),
        fmap show (faces file),
        fmap show (polylines file)]   

data ObjFileLine =
    V ObjVertex
    | VT ObjTexture
    | VN ObjNormal
    | VP ObjParameter
    | F ObjFace
    | L ObjPolyLine
    deriving Eq

instance Show ObjFileLine where
    show (V v) = show v
    show (VT t) = show t
    show (VN n) = show n
    show (VP p) = show p
    show (F f) = show f
    show (L l) = show l
```

And a `Obj/Parse.hs` for the parsers which looks like this:

```
module Obj.Parse ( parseFile ) where

import Control.Applicative ((<|>), liftA)
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

import Obj.Obj

-- Parser combinators for an OBJ file.

-- Parse numbers.
parseSign :: (Num a) => ReadP a
parseSign = do
    sign <- option '+' (char '-')
    return $ if sign == '+' then 1 else -1

parseInteger :: ReadP Int
parseInteger = do
    sign <- parseSign
    s <- many1 $ satisfy isDigit
    return $ sign * read s

parseDouble :: ReadP Double
parseDouble = (do
    sign <- parseSign
    int <- many1 $ satisfy isDigit
    char '.'
    decimal <- many1 $ satisfy isDigit
    let s = int ++ "." ++ decimal
    return $ sign * read s
    )

parseNumber = fmap fromIntegral parseInteger <|> parseDouble


-- Parse elements of an OBJ file.
vertex :: ReadP ObjVertex
vertex = do
    string "v "
    numbers <- sepBy parseNumber skipSpaces
    case numbers of
        [a, b, c]    -> return $ Vertex a b c
        [a, b, c, d] -> return $ Vertex4 a b c d
        _            -> fail ""


texture :: ReadP ObjTexture
texture = do
    string "vt "
    numbers <- sepBy parseNumber skipSpaces
    case numbers of
        [a]       -> return $ Texture1 a
        [a, b]    -> return $ Texture2 a b
        [a, b, c] -> return $ Texture3 a b c
        _         -> fail ""

normal :: ReadP ObjNormal
normal = do
    string "vn "
    numbers <- sepBy parseNumber skipSpaces
    case numbers of
        [a, b, c] -> return $ Normal a b c
        _         -> fail ""

parameter :: ReadP ObjParameter
parameter = do
    string "vp "
    numbers <- sepBy parseNumber skipSpaces
    case numbers of
        [a]       -> return $ Parameter1 a
        [a, b]    -> return $ Parameter2 a b
        [a, b, c] -> return $ Parameter3 a b c
        _         -> fail ""

vertexIndex :: ReadP ObjVertexIndex
vertexIndex = do
        a <- parseInteger
        return $ VertexIndex a
    <|> do
        a <- parseInteger
        char '/'
        b <- parseInteger
        return $ VertexTexture a b
    <|> do
        a <- parseInteger
        string "//"
        b <- parseInteger
        return $ VertexNormal a b
    <|> do
        a <- parseInteger
        char '/'
        b <- parseInteger
        char '/'
        c <- parseInteger
        return $ VertexTextureNormal a b c

face :: ReadP ObjFace
face = do
    string "f "
    vertices <- sepBy vertexIndex skipSpaces
    return $ Face vertices

objPolyline :: ReadP ObjPolyLine
objPolyline = do
    string "l "
    elements <- sepBy parseInteger skipSpaces
    return $ Line elements


-- Parse any line of an OBJ file.
parseLine :: ReadP ObjFileLine
parseLine =
    liftA V vertex
    <|> liftA VT texture
    <|> liftA VN normal
    <|> liftA VP parameter
    <|> liftA F face
    <|> liftA L objPolyline

-- An empty OBJ file.
emptyFile :: ObjFile
emptyFile = File {
    vertices = [],
    textures = [],
    normals = [],
    parameters = [],
    faces = [],
    polylines = []
}

-- Fold a list of lines to an obj file.
fileFromLines :: [ObjFileLine] -> ObjFile
fileFromLines = foldl addLine emptyFile
    where
        addLine file (V vertex) = file { vertices = vertices file ++ [vertex] }
        addLine file (VT texture) = file { textures = textures file ++ [texture] }
        addLine file (VN normal) = file { normals = normals file ++ [normal] }
        addLine file (VP parameter) = file { parameters = parameters file ++ [parameter] }
        addLine file (F face) = file { faces = faces file ++ [face] }
        addLine file (L line) = file { polylines = polylines file ++ [line] }

-- Parse an OBJ file.
parseFile :: ReadP ObjFile
parseFile = fileFromLines <$> many (do
    line <- parseLine
    char '\n'
    return line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Read` provides compatibility with `ReadP`.

```
parseInteger :: ReadP Int
parseInteger = readS_to_P $ readsPrec 0

parseDouble :: ReadP Double
parseDouble = readS_to_P $ readsPrec 0
```

Note that usually, `Show` instances are supposed to produce strings that can be pasted into .hs files to reproduce the value.

Why not have `ObjFile = [ObjFileLine]`, and `ObjFileLine` as a single type with 15 constructors?